# 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; In connecting 3 tables Where I have an error?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day what have I change in my query?

```
'SELECT a.first_name,
       a.last_name,
       a.birth_date,
       a.email,
       a.aba_email,
       a.phone,
       a.mobile_phone,
FROM passport a
INNER JOIN USER c ON a.id=c.passport_id
INNER JOIN consultant b ON b.user_id=c.id
WHERE c.id = :user_id
  AND b.create_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(:begin_date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(:end_date,"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))'
```

I got below Error

[image]

Comment: you have put an extra , just before the from keyword

Answer (score 1):

I think its the comma after mobile_phone, you only need commas when there is another column after it.

```
'SELECT a.first_name,
       a.last_name,
       a.birth_date,
       a.email,
       a.aba_email,
       a.phone,
       a.mobile_phone
FROM passport a
INNER JOIN USER c ON a.id=c.passport_id
INNER JOIN consultant b ON b.user_id=c.id
WHERE c.id = :user_id
  AND b.create_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(:begin_date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(:end_date,"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))'
```